# Adding variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, web, addition

I am looking for some help.
I'd like to be able to add 2 variables and then set one of the variables to a higher digit.

```
function gain_points() {
var total_points = parseInt(0)
var points_per_click = parseInt(1)
var points_per_second = parseInt(0)}
```

I'd like to be able to add total_points and points_per_click together, and then for that to increase total_points.

Is this possible?

Comment: So add them together....

Comment: `parseInt(0)` etc are redundant; you gain nothing over just saying `0`.  `parseInt` is for when you have a string that you need to be a number instead, and want to make sure it's interpreted as an integer rather than a float.

Comment: What do you want to do with `points_per_second`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having var total_points defined in the gain_points function it will be defined every time the function is called and assigned to the value of 0.

You may want to consider something like this:

```
var total_points = parseInt(0);
var points_per_click = parseInt(1);
var points_per_second = parseInt(0);

function gain_points() {
    total_points = total_points + points_per_click;
}
```

This allows total_points to continue to increment every time that function is called.

You also don't need to use the parseInt(); The following would be just fine instead:

```
var total_points = 0;
var points_per_click = 1;
var points_per_second = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
total_points = total_points + points_per_click;
```

Is that what you are saying??

Sorry, can't comment, not enough rep...